# How to determine which number occurs most often in an array?

Tags: delphi

How do I determine which value occurs the most after I filled the array with 100 random values which are between 1 and 11?

Comment: sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: I think your tutor expected you to write the answer rather than find it online

Comment: None of the answers sofar presents the answer where more than one number occurs most often.

Comment: @LURD what do you expect them to do? The question is asking for only 1 value. If multiple values have the same number of most occurrences, obviously you have to pick which value to return.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I'm aware that the question is searching for "which number", but without pointing out that the correct answer can include multiple numbers, the result will be biased towards lower numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  function Calculate: Integer;
  var
    Numbers: array [1..100] of Byte;
    Counts: array [1..11] of Byte;
    I: Byte;
  begin
    // Fill the array with random numbers
    for I := Low(Numbers) to High(Numbers) do
      Numbers[I] := Random(11) + 1;
    // Count the occurencies
    ZeroMemory(@Counts, SizeOf(Counts));
    for I := Low(Numbers) to High(Numbers) do
      Inc(Counts[Numbers[I]]);
    // Identify the maximum
    Result := Low(Counts);
    for I := Low(Counts) + 1 to High(Counts) do
      if Counts[I] > Counts[Result] then
        Result := I;
  end;

begin
  ShowMessage(Calculate.ToString);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is a simple question [...]

Yes

> but I can't seem to find any straight answers online.

You shouldn't be searching for solutions on-line; instead, you should start to think about how to design an algorithm able to solve the problem. For this, you may need pen and paper.

First, we need some data to work with:

```pascal
const
  ListLength = 100;
  MinValue = 1;
  MaxValue = 11;

function MakeRandomList: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  SetLength(Result, ListLength);
  for var i := 0 to High(Result) do
    Result[i] := MinValue + Random(MaxValue - MinValue + 1);
end;
```

The `MakeRandomList` function creates a dynamic array of integers. The array contains `ListLength = 100` integers ranging from `MinValue = 1` to `MaxValue = 11`, as desired.

Now, given such a list of integers,

```pascal
var L := MakeRandomList;
```

how do we find the most frequent value?

Well, if we were to solve this problem without a computer, using only pen and paper, we would probably count the number of times each distinct value (1, 2, ..., 11) occurs in the list, no?

Then we would only need to find the value with the greatest frequency.

For instance, given the data

```
2, 5, 1, 10, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 5
```

we would count to find the frequencies

```
X   Freq
2   2
5   3
1   2
10  1
7   1
8   1
```

Then we read the table from the top line to the bottom line to find the row with the greatest frequency, constantly keeping track of the current winner.

Now that we know *how* to solve the problem, it is trivial to write a piece of code that performs this algorithm:

```pascal
procedure FindMostFrequentValue(const AList: TArray<Integer>);
type
  TValueAndFreq = record
    Value: Integer;
    Freq: Integer;
  end;
var
  Frequencies: TArray<TValueAndFreq>;
begin

  if Length(AList) = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('List is empty.');

  SetLength(Frequencies, MaxValue - MinValue + 1);

  // Step 0: Label the frequency list items

  for var i := 0 to High(Frequencies) do
    Frequencies[i].Value := i + MinValue;

  // Step 1: Obtain the frequencies

  for var i := 0 to High(AList) do
  begin
    if not InRange(AList[i], MinValue, MaxValue) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Value out of range: %d', [AList[i]]);
    Inc(Frequencies[AList[i] - MinValue].Freq);
  end;

  // Step 2: Find the winner

  var Winner: TValueAndFreq;
  Winner.Value := 0;
  Winner.Freq := 0;

  for var i := 0 to High(Frequencies) do
    if Frequencies[i].Freq > Winner.Freq then
      Winner := Frequencies[i];

  ShowMessageFmt('The most frequent value is %d with a count of %d.',
    [Winner.Value, Winner.Freq]);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi has a [`TDictionary`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary) class, which you can use to implement a frequency map, eg:

```pascal
uses 
  ..., System.Generics.Collections;

function MostFrequent(Arr: array of Integer) : Integer;
var
  Frequencies: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
  I, Freq, MaxFreq: Integer;
  Elem: TPair<Integer, Integer>;
begin
  Frequencies := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create;
  // Fill the dictionary with numbers
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do begin
    if not Frequencies.TryGetValue(Arr[I], Freq) then Freq := 0;
    Frequencies.AddOrSetValue(Arr[I], Freq + 1);
  end;  
  // Identify the maximum
  Result := 0; 
  MaxFreq := 0;
  for Elem in Frequencies do begin
    if Elem.Value > MaxFreq then begin
      MaxFreq := Elem.Value;
      Result := Elem.Key;
    end;
  end;
  Frequencies.Free;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  Numbers: array [1..100] of Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Fill the array with random numbers
  for I := Low(Numbers) to High(Numbers) do
    Numbers[I] := Random(11) + 1;
  // Identify the maximum
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(MostFrequent(Numbers)));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also still learning and therefore feel that the way I approached this problem might be a little closer to the way would have done:

```
procedure TForm1.GetMostOccuring;
var
  arrNumbers : array[1..100] of Integer;
  iNumberWithMost : Integer;
  iNewAmount, iMostAmount : Integer;
  I, J : Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 100 do
    arrNumbers[I] := Random(10) + 1;

  iMostAmount := 0;

  for I := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    iNewAmount := 0;

    for J := 1 to 100 do
      if I = arrNumbers[J] then
        inc(iNewAmount);

    if iNewAmount > iMostAmount then
    begin
      iMostAmount := iNewAmount;
      iNumberWithMost := I;
    end;
  end;

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(iNumberWithMost));
end;
```

I hope this is not completely useless.
It is just a simple answer to a simple question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).